# Hide one container without hiding all

Tags: javascript, css

Need to hide an entire `<div>` if a profile image is missing, but allow remaining `<div>` with the same class visible. My jsfiddle seems close, but can anyone check my work?

My efforts also need to happen within the CSS/JS page of a closed system (Springshare/LibGuides), meaning I cannot add any inline calls or the like.

```js
$(() => {
  var src = $('img').attr('src');
  if (src === '//libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/common/images/profile.jpg'){
    $('.s-lib-featured-profile-container').hide();
    } 
  else {
    $('.s-lib-featured-profile-container').show();
  }
})
```

```html
<div class="s-lib-featured-profile-container"><a href="/prf.php?account_id=127256">
    <div class="s-lib-featured-profile-image">
      <img src="//libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/common/images/profile.jpg" alt="Julie Brewer's picture">
    </div>
    <div class="s-lib-profile-div s-lib-featured-profile-name">Julie Brewer</div></a>
</div>
 
 
 
<div class="s-lib-featured-profile-container"><a href="/prf.php?account_id=131922">
    <div class="s-lib-featured-profile-image">
      <img src="//libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/accounts/131922/profiles/125264/Caldwell_John.jpg" alt="John Caldwell's picture">
    </div>
    <div class="s-lib-profile-div s-lib-featured-profile-name">John Caldwell</div></a>
</div>
```

Please check jsfiddle example for further details:

https://jsfiddle.net/Raser/nq5swa10/3/

Ultimately, using the `img` & `src` calls, the code should hide the entire `<div class="s-lib-featured-profile-container">` that contains "Julie Brewer" and show the entire `<div class="s-lib-featured-profile-container">` that contains "John Caldwell".

Thanks for any assistance!

Comment: _"Ultimately, using the img & src calls the code"_ What do you mean by that? How is an html tag calling code? I also don't see how it would hide if the image is missing. You're only checking what the src on the image is equal to.

Comment: @dustytrash I believe that's the default profile image and the OP only wants to showcase ones that are provided by the user.

Comment: So select each image and then loop over them. Look to see if its source and then select the grand parent. Currently you select all the images, you look at the source for the first one, and then you select all the `s-lib-featured-profile-container` and alter them as a group.

Comment: Yes, @zfrisch is correct. And I realized a comma may have helped my description there! Hide default profile images, and display those "divs/containers" where a user has uploaded an image.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to loop all the divs which contain your desired image. Note that the browser adds the current scheme to the urls which begin with `//`, so you can use some sort of `endsWith` like search.

```js
$(() => {
  $(".s-lib-featured-profile-container").each((index, container) => {
    var src = $(container).find('img').prop('src');
    console.log(src);
    if (src === 'https://libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/common/images/profile.jpg') {
      $(container).hide();
    }
  })
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>

</head>

<body>


  <div class="s-lib-featured-profile-container">
    <a href="/prf.php?account_id=127256">
      <div class="s-lib-featured-profile-image">
        <img src="//libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/common/images/profile.jpg" alt="Julie Brewer's picture">
      </div>
      <div class="s-lib-profile-div s-lib-featured-profile-name">Julie Brewer</div>
    </a>
  </div>



  <div class="s-lib-featured-profile-container">
    <a href="/prf.php?account_id=131922">
      <div class="s-lib-featured-profile-image">
        <img src="//libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/accounts/131922/profiles/125264/Caldwell_John.jpg" alt="John Caldwell's picture">
      </div>
      <div class="s-lib-profile-div s-lib-featured-profile-name">John Caldwell</div>
    </a>
  </div>



</body>

</html>
```

Comment: This did it! Thank you Taha!

Comment: You're welcome, but the main point is not to copy paste it directly, try to understand what the code does.

Comment: Indeed. I do see the distinction, and the additional line looping and checking each div with that initial class to see if they do or do not contain the profile image src. I'm definitely a front-end and UX designer who knows just enough back-end language to make some silly mistakes!  Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

You selected all the images and hide them, you need to iterate the images, then, for each image decide if to hide it or not.

```js
$(() => {
  var allItems = $('.s-lib-featured-profile-container');
  allItems.each(function(){
    var image = $(this).find('img');
    if (image && image.attr('src') === '//libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/common/images/profile.jpg'){
      $(this).hide();
    }
  });
})
```

```css
img{
 width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="s-lib-featured-profile-container"><a href="/prf.php?account_id=127256">
    <div class="s-lib-featured-profile-image">
      <img src="//libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/common/images/profile.jpg" alt="Julie Brewer's picture">
    </div>
    <div class="s-lib-profile-div s-lib-featured-profile-name">Julie Brewer</div></a>
</div>
 
 
 
<div class="s-lib-featured-profile-container"><a href="/prf.php?account_id=131922">
    <div class="s-lib-featured-profile-image">
      <img src="//libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/accounts/131922/profiles/125264/Caldwell_John.jpg" alt="John Caldwell's picture">
    </div>
    <div class="s-lib-profile-div s-lib-featured-profile-name">John Caldwell</div></a>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of using [`.each`](http://api.jquery.com/each/), you can use the JQuery [`.filter`](http://api.jquery.com/filter/) method to filter out those image containers that have an image with a default picture. Then simply hide them using [`.hide`](http://api.jquery.com/hide/).

### Code:

```
var with_default_profile = $(".s-lib-featured-profile-image")
  .filter(function() {
    return $(this).find("img")
    .attr("src") === "//libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/common/images/profile.jpg";
  })
  with_default_profile.hide();
```

---

### Code With Comments:

```
// grab all the image containers

var with_default_profile = $(".s-lib-featured-profile-image")

// filter the image containers by asking
// does this container have an img with src ".../jpg" ?

  .filter(function() {
    return $(this).find("img")
    .attr("src") === "//libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/common/images/profile.jpg";
  })

// hide all the images that answered the question with "yes".

  with_default_profile.hide();
```

---

### Why use `filter` over `each` ?

`Filter` applies the added benefit of making your code more readable and extensible. In the future if you look at the code you will know that it's filtering, not just iterating over a list.

### Is `filter` better than `each`?

It's debatable. With `each` you're iterating over the list `once` and hiding the elements. This is clearly more performant as the `filter`/`hide` method iterates and *then* hides each element, effectively iterating again. That being said, the performance difference is most likely negligible. The upside to using `filter` instead is higher code sanity, but `each` isn't so far removed that it is a wrong choice to make.

Basically...

***It's up to your discretion***

---

### Code Snippet:

```js
$(() => {
  var with_default_profile = $(".s-lib-featured-profile-image")
  .filter(function() {
    return $(this).find("img").attr("src") === "//libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/common/images/profile.jpg";
  })
  with_default_profile.hide();
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="s-lib-featured-profile-container"><a href="/prf.php?account_id=127256">
    <div class="s-lib-featured-profile-image">
      <img src="//libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/apps/common/images/profile.jpg" alt="Julie Brewer's picture">
    </div>
    <div class="s-lib-profile-div s-lib-featured-profile-name">Julie Brewer</div></a>
</div>
 
 
 
<div class="s-lib-featured-profile-container"><a href="/prf.php?account_id=131922">
    <div class="s-lib-featured-profile-image">
      <img src="//libapps.s3.amazonaws.com/accounts/131922/profiles/125264/Caldwell_John.jpg" alt="John Caldwell's picture">
    </div>
    <div class="s-lib-profile-div s-lib-featured-profile-name">John Caldwell</div></a>
</div>
```